# How to catch an exception if it's caused by a specific function

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, scikit-learn

*Problem:*

sklearn allows creating user-defined distance functions to be used in several algorithms (for example KNN). However, it tests the user-defined function by creating [a random numpy array](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.pyx) (`__init__` of `class PyFuncDistance(DistanceMetric)` at the end of the page). My function is defined for categorical variables and to speed up the calculations I am passing a dictionary to the distance function that I build in advance. Naturally, when sklearn passes the float array for testing, it raises a KeyError because the dictionary only has attribute values as the keys.

*Code:*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import cross_validation

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c", "d"], (200, 4)))   

for col in df:
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(df[col])
    df[col] = le.transform(df[col])

value_dict = df[0].value_counts().to_dict()

def custom_distance(point1, point2, value_dict):
    #this is not the actual distance function, just a simplified version for reproducibility
    distance = .0
    for i in range(1, len(point1)+1):
        distance += abs(value_dict[point1[i]] - value_dict[point2[i]])
    return distance

neigh_custom = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10, metric=custom_distance, 
                        metric_params = {"value_dict": value_dict})

scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(neigh_custom, df.ix[:,1:], df.ix[:,0], cv=10)
```

*Question:*

To make sure the errors are not caused by the original data but by the test, can I catch that exception only if it is raised by `__init__` of `PyFuncDistance`? Currently I am checking whether the number is between 0 and 1 to understand if it is produced randomly but I don't think it is a good practice.

Comment: I think `KNeighborsClassifier` calls `sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.DistanceMetric.get_metric` and it calls `sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.PyFuncDistance.__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import traceback
import sys


try:
    scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(neigh_custom, df.ix[:,1:], df.ix[:,0], cv=10)
except Exception, err:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    sam =  traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,
                                          exc_traceback)
    if 'PyFuncDistance.__init__' in sam[-3]:
        print 'I knew it'
```

If you want to raise exception for other issues you can use 'raise' and use sam to print traceback call issue

Hope this help!